# Access - Date less than another date in an IIF expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
expr1: iif([field1]="No" & ([date1]<[date2]),"1","2"))
```

I'm sure there is a simple answer to my problem, but I can't see to find one elsewhere.  I have an iif expression in a field with two criteria checks.  I can't seem to get them to work together.

The date format is general.  "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss"

It appears to be failing on the date check.  It should be looking at where field1 = "no" and where date1 is less than date 2 but it seems to only find records where date1 is null where there are plenty records where date 1 isn't null but is less than date 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` operator is used to concatenate strings.  Use the logical `AND` instead.

```
iif([field1]="No" AND ([date1]<[date2]),"1","2")
```

Note I assumed *[date1]* and *[date2]* are both Date/Time datatype.  If one or both are text datatype, convert them to the corresponding date value for the comparison.

Comment: FACE PALM.  How did I miss that.  Sometimes the simplest problems elude...  Thanks, buddy.